# Need help with Gronwall lemma consequence

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

suppose we have an equation 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\xi(t) + a(t) = 0.$$
Integrating
$$\xi(T) + \int_0^T a(t) = \xi(0)$$
and using a bound on $a$, we have
$$\xi(T) \leq \xi(0) + \beta\int_0^T\xi(t)$$
Applying the integral form of Gronwall's inequality tells us that
$$\xi(T) \leq \xi(0)e^{\beta T}.$$
How do I use this to show that
$$\xi(t) \leq K\xi(0)$$
where $t \in [0,T]$?

Comment: Put $K=e^{\beta T}$, or did I miss something? Note that $\beta\ge0$, so $0\le t\le T$ implies $1\le e^{\beta t}\le e^{\beta T}$. On second thought, maybe your difficulty is that you haven't noticed that you in fact get $\xi(t) \leq \xi(0)e^{\beta t}$ for all $t\in[0,T]$, not only for $t=T$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Your second thought is right. This is because I could have integrated from $[0,s]$ instead of $[0,T]$ for any $s \in [0,T]$, right?